# Jetpack Compose Bottom Sheet initialization error

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack compose 1.0.0-beta01, I am calling the BottomSheetScaffold like this:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetContent = { Text("") },
    sheetShape = Shapes.large,
    backgroundColor = AppTheme.colors.uiBackground,
    modifier = modifier
    
) { (content) }
```

... and getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The initial value must have an associated anchor.

Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: for me comment height in content, solved my problem  `Row(/*Modifier.height(220.dp)*/) `

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't forget to add the following atribute:

> sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp

So your code should be like this:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
    scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
    sheetContent = { Text("") },
    sheetShape = Shapes.large,
    sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp, // <--- new line
    backgroundColor = AppTheme.colors.uiBackground,
    modifier = modifier
    
) { (content) }
```

Comment: That worked for me, but I have no idea why! Can you explain?

Comment: @Dambakk hold Ctrl and click BottomSheetScaffold

You'll see that the swipeable Modifier uses sheetPeekHeight via its anchors :)

Answer (score 19):

When bottomSheetState is expand, `sheetContent` must have real content to show.

You need check this.

Comment: That was my case. Thanks for insight.

Comment: To be specific it must have a target state which is not the same as initial state (e.g. ```sheetPeekHeight = 0```), so content with ```0``` height won't work as well.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue when using ModalBottomSheetLayout, and my compose material version is 1.2.0-rc02
androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0-rc02
I want to show the bottom modal when one item is selected, and if no item is selected, the modal should be empty.

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = modalBottomSheetState,
    sheetContent = {
        EditProgressContent(book = book)
    }
) { ... }

@Composable
fun EditProgressContent(book: Book?) {
    if (book == null) return
    Text(book.title)
}
```

When book is null, I got the same crash. There is no peekHeight parameter for ModalBottomSheetLayout, so I have to add a pixel when book is null

```
@Composable
fun EditProgressContent(book: Book?) {
    if (book == null) { 
        Box(modifier = Modifier.size(1.dp)
        return
    }
    Text(book.title)
}
```

The code looks silly, hope it can be fixed from Google.

Comment: Maybe because you open before the Launched Contents, try use a delay to open via ModalBottomSheetState

Answer (score 1):

In case you end up on this page because you use the `BackdropScaffold`, the suggested solution does the trick as well. Simply set the `peekHeight`.
For example like this:

```
BackdropScaffold(
        appBar = {},
        backLayerContent = {},
        frontLayerContent = {},
        peekHeight = 0.dp
    )
```

Then Preview works like a charm again.

Fun fact though: Don't set it to `56.dp` which is the default init value it normally should be initialised with (value of `BackdropScaffoldDefaults.PeekHeight`). `56.dp` results in the anchor rendering problem in my current setup.
*(Using compose version '1.1.1')*

Answer (score 1):

On new version, this error happens when the initial State is `Expanded`, where try to open the Modal before launched. Try launcher via ModalBottomSheetState from LaunchedEffect (maybe can need a delay)

Comment: some code makes things predictable!